# How to write two texts inside multiple bars in a horizontal bar graph matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, label, bar-chart

My code so far gives me something that looks like this:

[image: Horizontal Bar plot sample]

I am wanting to write in the bars themselves if possible to get something like this:

[image: Desired Horizontal Bar plot]

Here's my base code so far:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pandas.DataFrame(dict(graph=['Fruits & Vegetables','Bakery'],
                           p=[round(0.942871692205*100,5), round(0.933348641475*100,5)],
                           q=[round(0.941649166881*100,5),round(0.931458324883*100,5)],
                           r=[round(0.940803376393*100,5),round(0.929429068047*100,5)],
                          ))

ind = np.arange(len(df))
width = 0.25

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(ind, df.p, width, color='red', label='Accrate>=80')
ax.barh(ind + width, df.q, width, color='green', label='Accrate>=79')
ax.barh(ind + 2*width, df.r, width, color='blue', label='Accrate>=78')
                           
ax.set(yticks=ind + 2*width, yticklabels=df.graph, ylim=[2*width - 1, len(df)])
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.05))

plt.show()
```

I'd like to put the number text as shown in the desired plot link! How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the logic of the number is, but with [ax.text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html) you can do something like this:

i = 1
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = ['r','g','b']
labels = [80, 79, 78]

```
for ii, col in enumerate('pqr'):
    bars = ax.barh(ind + width*ii, df[col], width, color=colors[ii], label=f'Accrate>={labels[ii]}')
    for bar in bars:
        (x,y), h, w = bar.get_xy(), bar.get_height(), bar.get_width()

        ax.text(x+5, y+h/2, str(i), color='w', weight='bold', va='center')
        ax.text(x+w-5, y+h/2, str(6+i), color='w', weight='bold', va='center', ha='right')
        i += 1
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, Quang, got it solved with this response, highly appreciate your help!